# Transform csv multiple columns to single column

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk

I have 1 csv data with multiple column, without header:

```
5,-3,0
3,2,5
-2,4,4
0,2,1
2,-1,-2
```

Then I would like to transpose it into single column, starting from first column.
The expected output is below:

```
 5
 3
-2
 0
 2
-3
 2
 4
 2
-1
 0
 5
 4
 1
-2
```

Anyone have a clue how to solve this problem?

What I have done is using excel formula: `=INDEX($A$1:$C$4,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS($A$1:$C$4)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS($A$1:$C$4),COLUMNS($A$1:$C4))+1)` and ending with single column but start from first row.

I am looking for faster way to do this, using script for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input file isn't absolutely massive (e.g. millions of lines of millions of fields) and so can fit in memory then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F',' '
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[NR,i]=$i }
    END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) print a[j,i] }
' file
5
3
-2
0
2
-3
2
4
2
-1
0
5
4
1
-2
```

Comment: Pardon for my ignorance, this is my first time to try. How to use above script? Should I paste all in Terminal, in the same directory with the file?

Comment: Yes. Why not just try that though and THEN ask if it doesn't work? Preemptively - the `$` at the start is my prompt (an extremely common one that many people use), it's not part of the command. To learn AWK, which everyone doing any text processing Unix should know, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @user97103 The `awk` command reads from a file called `file`. That file contains your data.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, its worked. But my data has 478 column and 69000 row. How to save it directly into a new file using above script?

Comment: Not sure why you said `But my data has 478 column and 69000 row` - is there an issue you think is related to that? In Unix to save the output of any command to a file named `foo` just add `> foo` to the end of the command so in this case `awk 'script' file > foo`.

Comment: To learn shell scripting you could get the book Shell Scripting Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach by Chris Johnson.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will find the book.

Comment: I have try it `awk 'script' file.csv > file2.csv` and change the script with above, but it returned the same result with the input, not a csv with single column.

Comment: My guess is that `file.csv` doesn't contain space-separated fields as you show in your example and the fields are actually separated by something else, e.g. commas or semi-colons or pipes or something. It's extremely important when posting an example in a question that it does actually look like your real data. If my guess is correct then please edit your question to use the same separator in  your example as you have in  your real data. If that's not the problem then edit your question to show the output of `head file.csv | cat -TEv` and copy/paste **exactly** the script you're executing.

Comment: I am sorry, I got `cat: illegal option -- T`. I am using mac, and try to use `cat --help` and returned with `cat: illegal option -- -`

Comment: OK, then don't include `T` in the options and just use `cat -Ev`. If you don't have `E` then  use `cat -v`.

Comment: I have edit the question, it's using comma based on the result from `cat -v`

Comment: I'd edited my answer to match.

Comment: Thank you, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `awk` if you have Gnu `datamash` is to do a simple transposition specifying `,` as the separa`-t`or

```
datamash transpose -t, < file

5,3,-2,0,2
-3,2,4,2,-1
0,5,4,1,-2
```

and then you can just replace `,` with `\n` by piping it through `tr`

```
datamash transpose -t, < file | tr ',' '\n'
5
3
-2
0
2
-3
2
4
2
-1
0
5
4
1
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `itertools` module and it's function `chain` , to chain iterators and print them sequentially.

```
python3 -c '
import sys, itertools as it
fs,rs = ",","\n"
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  L = []
  for l in f:
    F = l.rstrip(rs).split(fs)
    if not len(L):
      L += [[] for i in range(0,len(F))]
    for nc,e in enumerate(F):
      L[nc].append(e)
for x in it.chain(*L): print(x)
' file
```

---

Output:-

```
5
3
-2
0
2
-3
2
4
2
-1
0
5
4
1
-2
```